# Shank Transformation to Lebniez series to find Pi recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I found a simple series named the Lebniez series for finding Pi.

$$1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} - \dots = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

I made this in Python. I then realised that because it is an infinite series, and it will give an approximation. Additionally the convergence rate is very slow.

Here is the program I made after learning about series acceleration through the Shank Transform:

```
def lebniez(n):
    pi = 0
    n = n + 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        if(i % 2 == 1):
            pi -= 1 / (2*i - 1)
        else:
            pi += 1/(2*i - 1)
    pi = abs(4 * pi)
    return pi

def accelrate(n,depth):
    if depth == 1:
        a = lebniez(n + 1)
        b = lebniez(n)
        c = lebniez(n-1)
        return (a*c - b*b)/(a + c - 2*b) 
    a = accelrate(n + 1,depth - 1)
    b = accelrate(n,depth - 1)
    c = accelrate(n-1,depth - 1)
    return (a*c - b*b)/(a + c - 2*b)
```

I have applied the shank transformation and gotten a new series. After this I continuously apply it recursively. However using recursion has made it very slow. If I keep accelerating the function then after some depth the accuracy starts decreasing.

Answer (score 4):

#### Repeated computations

Part of the reason it is slow is that a lot of the computations are repeated many times.  For example, if you diagram the calls for `accelrate(3,3)` you get something like this (where A is a call to `accelrate` and L is a call to `lebniez`):

```
                                                                A(3,3)
                                                                   | 
                      +--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
                      |                                            |                                            |
                   A(4,2)                                       A(3,2)                                       A(2,2)
                      |                                            |                                            |
       +--------------+--------------+              +--------------+--------------+              +--------------+--------------+
       |              |              |              |              |              |              |              |              |
    A(5,1)         A(4,1)         A(3,1)         A(4,1)         A(3,1)         A(2,1)         A(3,1)         A(2,1)         A(1,1)
       |              |              |              |              |              |              |              |              |
  +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
L(6) L(5) L(4) L(5) L(4) L(3) L(4) L(3) L(2) L(5) L(4) L(3) L(4) L(3) L(2) L(3) L(2) L(1) L(4) L(3) L(2) L(3) L(2) L(1) L(2) L(1) L(0)
```

Notice the repeated calls, like A(4,1) or L(3).

If you were to do this for `accelrate(6,6)` you would find that `lebniez(6)` is called 114351 times and there are 591,219 total calls to `lebniez()`.  Also, there 41,361 calls to `accelrate(6,1)` and a total of 295,204 recursive calls to `accelerate()`.

#### cache computations

One way to address repeated computations is to use a cache to save previous computations.  For example, cache the computation of A(3,1) the first time it is called and reuse it in later computations. [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) can be used like so:

```
import functools as ft

@ft.lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def lebniez(n):
    pi = 0
    n = n + 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        if(i % 2 == 1):
            pi -= 1 / (2*i - 1)
        else:
            pi += 1/(2*i - 1)
    pi = abs(4 * pi)
    return pi

@ft.lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def accelrate(n,depth):
    if depth == 1:
        a = lebniez(n + 1)
        b = lebniez(n)
        c = lebniez(n-1)
    else:
        a = accelrate(n + 1,depth - 1)
        b = accelrate(n,depth - 1)
        c = accelrate(n-1,depth - 1)

    return (a*c - b*b)/(a + c - 2*b)
```

#### Numerical stability

Your second question has to do with the stability of numerical calculations (an entire field of its own).  Basically, most calculations on a computer have limited precision (i.e., number of bits) which can cause problems.  This article on [Floating-point Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) explains it better than I could.  Check out the example of computing pi at the end.

Also, this article on the [Shanks transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation) says the expression you are using, `(a*c - b*b)/(a + c - 2*b)`, is less numerically stable than another expression for the transform, `a - (a-b)**2/((a-b)-(b-c))`.

Comment: Don't know if you saw this message from [Dhaval Bothra](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/228467/dhaval-bothra). "Hello I am brother of Coder B . I wanted to say thanks for this Answer to Root Two. Sorry I could not comment but a Big THANKS FOR ANSWERING"